# Navigation broken in Sitecore Page Editor during Edit related item

Tags: editor, sitecore, sitecore6

After updating Sitecore 6.3 to 6.6, the Main Navigation is broken in the Sitecore Page Editor when "Edit related item" is clicked.

It looks like this:
[image: Broken Navigation]

It even stays like this when closing the "Edit related item" frame.

Here is the text from that screen:

> {"commands":[{"click":"chrome:common:edititem({command:\"webedit:open\"})","header":"","icon":"/~/icon/SoftwareV2/16x16/cubes_blue.png.aspx","isDivider":false,"tooltip":"Dieses Item im Content Editor bearbeiten.","type":"common"}],"contextItemUri":"sitecore://master/{78EBD797-ACA9-40BC-9ACE-961CD2296CDC}?lang=de-CH&ver=1","custom":{},"displayName":"Title","expandedDisplayName":null}KATA {"commands":[{"click":"chrome:common:edititem({command:\"webedit:open\"})","header":"","icon":"/~/icon/SoftwareV2/16x16/cubes_blue.png.aspx","isDivider":false,"tooltip":"Dieses Item im Content Editor bearbeiten.","type":"common"}],"contextItemUri":"sitecore://master/{F195AD36-86EE-4C13-883B-761E300C23AF}?lang=de-CH&ver=1","custom":{},"displayName":"Title","expandedDisplayName":null}REA {"commands":[{"click":"chrome:common:edititem({command:\"webedit:open\"})","header":"","icon":"/~/icon/SoftwareV2/16x16/cubes_blue.png.aspx","isDivider":false,"tooltip":"Dieses Item im Content Editor bearbeiten.","type":"common"}],"contextItemUri":"sitecore://master/{63438A98-FC6F-461D-89BB-7497B12FBAEF}?lang=de-CH&ver=1","custom":{},"displayName":"Title","expandedDisplayName":null}Patientensicherheit {"commands":[{"click":"chrome:common:edititem({command:\"webedit:open\"})","header":"","icon":"/~/icon/SoftwareV2/16x16/cubes_blue.png.aspx","isDivider":false,"tooltip":"Dieses Item im Content Editor bearbeiten.","type":"common"}],"contextItemUri":"sitecore://master/{FB9B0590-E933-4141-BA2B-F82C83A3343E}?lang=de-CH&ver=1","custom":{},"displayName":"Title","expandedDisplayName":null}Prozesse {"commands":[{"click":"chrome:common:edititem({command:\"webedit:open\"})","header":"","icon":"/~/icon/SoftwareV2/16x16/cubes_blue.png.aspx","isDivider":false,"tooltip":"Dieses Item im Content Editor bearbeiten.","type":"common"}],"contextItemUri":"sitecore://master/{0F1334E0-9BB7-4657-9DC4-884F6E1133C9}?lang=de-CH&ver=1","custom":{},"displayName":"Title","expandedDisplayName":null}Dokumente {"commands":[{"click":"chrome:common:edititem({command:\"webedit:open\"})","header":"","icon":"/~/icon/SoftwareV2/16x16/cubes_blue.png.aspx","isDivider":false,"tooltip":"Dieses Item im Content Editor bearbeiten.","type":"common"}],"contextItemUri":"sitecore://master/{8D18489B-B7F3-442B-9958-7D1FDBDC9010}?lang=de-CH&ver=1","custom":{},"displayName":"Title","expandedDisplayName":null}Telefonlisten

Anyone knows what this is and how I can fix it?

Thanks in advance :)

**EDIT:**

Code of .ascx:

```
<%@ Control Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" 

CodeBehind="Header.ascx.cs" Inherits="ZGKS.Intranet.WebApp.Frontend.sublayouts.Header" %>
<%@ Register Src="NavLayer.ascx" TagName="NavLayer" TagPrefix="uc1" %>
<%@ Register Src="~/Frontend/sublayouts/SearchBox.ascx" TagName="SearchBox" TagPrefix="ZGKSControls" %>
<div class="head">
    <div class="line">
        <div class="unit sizeCol">
            <!-- mod NavService -->
            <div class="mod modNavService skinNavServiceHome">
                <div class="inner">
                    <div class="bd">
                        <ul>
                            <li><a href="/" title="Home" class="major">Home</a></li>
                            <li><span>
                                <asp:Literal ID="litWelcome" runat="server"></asp:Literal>
                                <asp:Literal ID="litUsername" runat="server"></asp:Literal></span></li>
                            <li class="last"><span>
                                <asp:Literal ID="litDate" runat="server"></asp:Literal></span></li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <!-- /mod NavService -->
            <!-- mod NavService -->
            <div class="mod modNavService">
                <div class="inner">
                    <!-- tpl NavService-navservice -->
                    <div class="bd">
                        <ul>
                            <asp:Literal ID="litNaviLinks" runat="server"></asp:Literal>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                    <!-- /tpl NavService-navservice -->
                </div>
            </div>
            <!-- /mod NavService -->
            <!-- mod Favourites -->
            <div class="mod modFavourites">
                <div class="inner">
                    <!-- tpl Favourites-favourites -->
                    <div class="hd">
                        <ul>
                            <li><a href="#" title="">Meine Favoriten</a>
                                <div class="favnavcontainer">
                                    <div class="wrap">
                                        <div class="list">
                                            <table>
                                                <tbody>
                                                    <tr>
                                                        <td>
                                                            <asp:Label ID="lblFavoritesDescription" runat="server" />
                                                        </td>
                                                    </tr>
                                                </tbody>
                                            </table>
                                            <table class="highlight">
                                                <tbody>
                                                    <asp:Repeater ID="rptFavorite" runat="server" OnItemCommand="RptFavoriteItemCommand">
                                                        <ItemTemplate>
                                                            <tr class="favoritemark">
                                                                <td>
                                                                    <a href="<%# Eval("Url") %>">
                                                                        <%# Eval("Title") %></a>
                                                                </td>
                                                                <td class="delete">
                                                                    <span>
                                                                        <asp:ImageButton ToolTip="Löschen" AlternateText="Löschen" ID="btnDeleteFav" runat="server"
                                                                            CommandName="delFav" CommandArgument='<%# Eval("ID") %>' ImageUrl="~/Frontend/Images/icons/clear.png" />
                                                                    </span>
                                                                </td>
                                                                <td class="edit" title="Editieren">
                                                                    <span></span>
                                                                </td>
                                                            </tr>
                                                        </ItemTemplate>
                                                    </asp:Repeater>
                                                </tbody>
                                            </table>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <a class="close" title="" href="#">Schliessen <span>|</span> X</a>
                                </div>
                            </li>
                            <li><a href="#" title="">Meine Systeme</a>
                                <div class="favnavcontainer">
                                    <div class="wrap">
                                        <div class="list">
                                            <table>
                                                <tbody>
                                                    <tr>
                                                        <td>
                                                            <asp:Label ID="lblSystemDescription" runat="server" />
                                                        </td>
                                                    </tr>
                                                </tbody>
                                            </table>
                                            <table class="highlight">
                                                <tbody>
                                                    <asp:Repeater ID="rptSysteme" runat="server">
                                                        <ItemTemplate>
                                                            <tr class="">
                                                                <td>
                                                                    <a target="_blank" href="<%# Eval("Url") %>">
                                                                        <%# Eval("Title") %></a>
                                                                </td>
                                                            </tr>
                                                        </ItemTemplate>
                                                    </asp:Repeater>
                                                </tbody>
                                            </table>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="modContent" style="padding: 0;">
                                        <div style="margin: 10px 0; margin-left: 10px;">
                                            <a target="_self" href='<%# MySystemLink %>' class="icon back" title="Zurück">
                                                <span>Meine Systeme bearbeiten</span>
                                            </a>
                                        </div>
                                        <a class="close" title="" href="#">Schliessen <span>|</span> X</a>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </li>
                            <li><a href="#" title="">Meine Alerts</a>
                                <div class="favnavcontainer">
                                    <div class="wrap">
                                        <div class="list">
                                            <table>
                                                <tbody>
                                                    <tr>
                                                        <td>
                                                            <asp:Label ID="lblAlertDescription" runat="server" />
                                                        </td>
                                                    </tr>
                                                </tbody>
                                            </table>
                                            <table class="highlight">
                                                <tbody>
                                                    <asp:Repeater ID="rptAlert" runat="server" OnItemCommand="RptAlertItemCommand">
                                                        <ItemTemplate>
                                                            <tr class="alertmark">
                                                                <td>
                                                                    <a href="<%# Eval("Url") %>">
                                                                        <%# Eval("Title") %></a>
                                                                </td>
                                                                <td class="delete">
                                                                    <span>
                                                                        <asp:ImageButton ToolTip="Löschen" AlternateText="Löschen" ID="btnDeleteAlert" runat="server"
                                                                            CommandName="delAlert" CommandArgument='<%# Eval("ID") %>' ImageUrl="~/Frontend/Images/icons/clear.png" />
                                                                    </span>
                                                                </td>
                                                                <td class="edit" title="Editieren">
                                                                    <span>&nbsp;</span>
                                                                </td>
                                                            </tr>
                                                        </ItemTemplate>
                                                    </asp:Repeater>
                                                </tbody>
                                            </table>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <a class="close" title="" href="#">Schliessen <span>|</span> X</a>
                                </div>
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                    <div class="bd">
                    </div>
                    <!-- /tpl Favourites-favourites -->
                </div>
            </div>
            <!-- /mod Favourites -->
        </div>
        <div class="unit sizeCol lastUnit">
            <div class="line">
                <!-- mod Logo -->
                <div class="mod modLogo">
                    <div class="inner">
                        <!-- tpl Logo-logo -->
                        <div class="bd">
                            <a href="/" title="">
                                <img class="screen" src="/Frontend/Images/logo.gif" width="291" height="27" alt="ZGKS"></a>
                        </div>
                        <!-- /tpl Logo-logo -->
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="line">
                <ZGKSControls:SearchBox ID="SearchBox" runat="server" />
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="line">
            <div class="unit size1of1">
                <uc1:NavLayer ID="NavLayer1" runat="server" />
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Can you paste .ascx code of your navigation?

Comment: Added .ascx code to the first post.

Comment: Make sure that /`website/webedit.css` is present in your inetpub folder, that you do not have it checked into your Visual Studio project (i.e it is not overwriting an updated file from 6.6 install)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is due to changes in the webedit.css stylesheet in Sitecore 6.6 from previous versions.

Make sure that `/website/webedit.css` is present in your inetpub folder, that you do not have it checked into your Visual Studio project, i.e it is not overwriting with a previous version of the file from your source control.